# webpack translation modules as companion files

Tags: webpack, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I need to compile translation files for each `.vue` file processed by webpack (vue-loader).
These translation files are not referenced in the `.vue`, they are companioned by translation files (then webpack cannot directly track them)

example:

```
myComponent1.vue
myComponent1.lang.en.yaml
myComponent1.lang.fr.yaml
...
```

In a SSR context:

- server-side: all companion files are loaded at startup and feed the i18n system with all languages
- client-side: files are loaded on demand through `import()` and feed the i18n system with the current language

note:
`require.context()`  is note suitable since it only works from a given directory structure.

does webpack offers such possibility ?

Comment: You might be able to use a separate entry points (or even a separate file) that imports both the .vue and the .yaml files. See: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#separate-app-and-vendor-entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution without any dedicated webpack loader/plugin.
Each component have to declare its "language packs":

```
registerMessages(locale => import(`json!yaml!./myComponent1.lang.${locale}.yaml`));

export default {
    ... component definition
}
```